# Stability of Nash embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider a smooth compact manifold $M^n$, endowed with a smooth metric $g$. Assume that there exists a dimension $N$ and and isometric embedding $u : (M^n,g) \to \mathbb{R}^N$, for instance $N=n+1$. 
Consider a small perturbation $g_\epsilon$ of $g$, we obtain an other manifold $(M^n,g_\epsilon)$. My question is about the stability of both the dimension and the embedding of Nash embedding theorem : if $g_\epsilon$ is close enough to $g$ in some $C^k$ topology for $k\geq 2$, is it true that there exists an isometric embedding $u_\epsilon : (M,g_\epsilon)\to \mathbb{R}^N$ which is close to $u$ ? 
The general case (see R Leo arxiv:1711.01709) seems to be open if $N$ is to low. I'm mostly interested in the case $N=n+1$. I wonder if the question is easier if I localize the problem :
In local coordinates, my question can be formulated in the following way : consider the unit ball $B^n(0,1)$ of dimension $n$, together with a metric $g$. Assume that I have an isometric embedding $u: (B^n(0,1),g) \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Consider a smooth metric $g_\epsilon$ closed to $g$. Is there an isometric embedding $u_\epsilon : (B^n(0,1),g) \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ close to $u$ ? 
What if I assume $g$ and $u$ to be analytic ? What if $g_\epsilon$ is analytic also ?

Comment: I believe the number $N$ can be uniformly chosen to be dependent only on $n=\dim M$. For example, taking $N = n^2 + 10 n + 3$ would suffice (see pg 223 of Gromov's PDR book). Of course this is not optimal.

Comment: My question was more about : $N$ is given, maybe not the dimension $n^2+10n+3$ (for instance consider a hypersurface $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$), do we have stability of both the dimension and the embedding ?

Comment: The generic Riemannian 3-manifold does not isometrically embed into 4-dimensional Euclidean space, so if you start with a Riemannian 3-manifold which does, small perturbations will not.

Comment: So you will have to use the dimension at least the one from Gromov's book.

Comment: @Dorian If $u$ is a free embedding (which obviously requires $N$ to be sufficiently large), then you get the stability. This is because the underlying differential operator is open on free maps. For non-free immersions this was a conjecture by Gromov and proved by R Leo (arxiv:1711.01709). I am not sure about the general case.

Comment: As @ChesterX says, you can choose $N$ to be independent of the Riemannian manifold and therefore keep it fixed when you perturb the metric. The proof of the theorem uses an implicit function theorem. An implicit function theorem always requires that every step be stable under perturbation, and the Nash theorem is no exception. So the answer is yes.

Comment: @ChesterX Thanks for your answers, I have eddited the post to add some assumptions. Maybe, the question is already understood if the variation of the metric is localized ?

Comment: @DeaneYang Have you a good reference where this can be checked ?

Comment: The changes you have made to the question still do not deal with the problem that the generic Riemannian metric in dimension $n$ does not locally isometrically embed into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, for any dimension $n\ge 3$, as I mentioned before, even for analytic metrics.

Comment: @Dorian A <i>very</i> heuristic argument is that in low codimension, the underlying operator becomes overdetermined, and so solutions (if exists) are more likely to be rigid. In fact, there are two papers by Berger-Bryant-Griffiths (MR0627257, MR0714831) which deals with this exact problem: both in local and global situation.

Comment: Stability for a free embedding follows from the second step of the Nash isometric embedding theorem, which is a perturbation theorem. Nash developed an ingenious, seemingly impossible, iteration method to prove this. Moser found a much easier proof. I dug around, and it appears to be presented nicely in https://dgerardv.github.io/files/poly__Nash_Moser_Feb2019.pdf. It’s all in chapters 3 and 4.

Comment: Gromov, in his book Partial Differential Relations, also proves a perturbation theorem for isometric embeddings that are not necessarily free. He also includes a proof of the Nash-Moser implicit function theorem. But his approach, using an ingenious argument using only elementary linear algebra and careful dimension counting, to solve underdetermined systems of PDEs, still requires the codimension to be greater than $1$.